# react-render-html: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I need to make a bubble rich text editor with `react-quill`, when I try make a content with rich editor then it's worked fine. but when I try to fetch data from my database with `react-render-html` then it does not work show me error like this:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
push../node_modules/react-render-html/node_modules/parse5/lib/tokenizer/preprocessor.js.module.exports.push../node_modules/react-render-html/node_modules/parse5/lib/tokenizer/preprocessor.js.Preprocessor.write
C:/Users/alami/OneDrive/Desktop/MERN stack/online shopping/client/node_modules/react-render-html/node_modules/parse5/lib/tokenizer/preprocessor.js:91
  88 |     else
  89 |         this.html = chunk;
  90 | 
> 91 |     this.lastCharPos = this.html.length - 1;
  92 |     this.endOfChunkHit = false;
  93 |     this.lastChunkWritten = isLastChunk;
  94 | };
```

I have tried code by this way:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Button, Descriptions } from "antd";
import renderHTML from "react-render-html";

function ProductInfo(props) {
  const [Product, setProduct] = useState({});
  useEffect(() => {
    setProduct(props.detail);
  }, [props.detail]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Descriptions title="Product Info">
        <Descriptions.Item label="Price">${Product.price}</Descriptions.Item>
        <Descriptions.Item label="Sold">{Product.sold}</Descriptions.Item>
        <Descriptions.Item label="View">{Product.views}</Descriptions.Item>
        <Descriptions.Item label="Description">
          <div>{renderHTML(Product.desc)}</div>
        </Descriptions.Item>
      </Descriptions>

      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <Button shape="round" type="danger">
          Contact me
        </Button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ProductInfo;
```

If I removed `renderHTML` from `{renderHTML(Product.desc)}` then It worked, but output show me `html` code, does not show plane text.

Any Suggestion Please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience its because Product.desc is fetched in an asynchronous manner so it will be undefined at some point. So when renderHTML tries to get the length, it tries to get the length of undefined at some point, before the fetching is finished.

Try this:

```
<Descriptions.Item label="Description">
          {Product.desc ? <div>{renderHTML(Product.desc)}</div> : null}
        </Descriptions.Item>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need state, since nothing is changing. Instead just pass props.detail.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Button, Descriptions } from 'antd';
import renderHTML from 'react-render-html';

function ProductInfo(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Descriptions title="Product Info">
        <Descriptions.Item label="Price">${props.detail.price}</Descriptions.Item>
        <Descriptions.Item label="Sold">{props.detail.sold}</Descriptions.Item>
        <Descriptions.Item label="View">{props.detail.views}</Descriptions.Item>
        <Descriptions.Item label="Description">
          <div>{renderHTML(props.detail.desc)}</div>
        </Descriptions.Item>
      </Descriptions>

      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Button shape="round" type="danger">
          Contact me
        </Button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ProductInfo;
```

Comment: Maybe your logic is almost same, what I have did, unfortunately I have got same error.

Comment: Then your component needs to handle the case when props.detail is undefined.

Comment: Thanks I got the solved by this logic: `{Product.desc ? <div>{renderHTML(Product.desc)}</div> : null}`

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you pass an undefined property to renderHtml. The root course is that we should know useEffect calls after the initial render of the HTML(knowledge on useEffect basics). So when react tries to render the HTML for the first time, the products.desc property is not declared its undefined(useEffect hasn't triggered yet).  You can handle it in different ways. I normally render the components which depend on the useEffect hook conditionally only after the useEffect set the states

```
{checkState? <MyComponent />:'Loading'}
```